# onClick to edit CheckBox data on ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, edit, fileoutputstream

I saved some text by using `FileOutputStream` to a file and then displayed them on a `ListView`.

I'm trying to edit the content by **first** check the checkbox of the item, then click a button to either Edit or Delete the data.

I did a lot of research but still couldn't understand how to implement this

Here are my codes

To show the data and display them on `ListView`

```
void ShowSavedFiles() {
    //SavedFiles = getApplicationContext().fileList();
    SavedFiles = getApplication().fileList();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            SavedFiles);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (adapter.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no Address !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

To edit the data by checking `CheckBox`, then press Edit button

```
void editData(){
    imgEditData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (choiceMode == false) {

                choiceMode = true;
                clickAble = false;
                multiSelectBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(addressActivity.this, "Edit ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        // change the checkbox state
                        CheckedTextView checkedTextView = ((CheckedTextView) view);
                        checkedTextView.setChecked(!checkedTextView.isChecked());
                    }
                });
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
                        = new ArrayAdapter<String>(addressActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                        SavedFiles);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }}
    });
}
```

a picture of it to better understand

[image]

Ignore the other buttons

Comment: You wanna to edit all check data after click edit button???

Comment: @ArpitPatel Basically I want to edit just ONE checked data but I don't know any alternatives I can use for `simple_list_item_multiple_choice`. But yes,edit the checked data after clicking the edit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `public class utils` and in it create a `public static ArrayList<Integer> positions`. And in `adapter` of `listview` add `setOnClickListener` on `CheckBox` that when it is clicked and checked you add that position to `public static array`.

```
public class Utils {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> positions =new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In `getView()` Function of your adapter after inflating layout add this

```
CheckBox cBox= (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.myCheckBox); // view is you view inflated
final int myPos= position; //position of cuurent item will be passed into getwiew function

        cBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox temp=(CheckBox)v;
                if(temp.isChecked()){
                    Utils.positions.add(myPos);
                }
                else{
                    Utils.positions.remove(myPos);
                }
            }
        });
```

In this way you can get all list of indexes in `Utils.postions` which are checked when you press button like edit delete etc. AND on click on these buttons you perform your required task on these indexes of main array passed to adapter

**Make sure you clear that `public static Arraylist` everytime you populate `list view`** YOU can do this by calling

```
Utils.positions.clear()
```

before notifying adapter everytime.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I should create an empty `ArrayList<Integer>` which will be filled everytime I click on the `CheckBox`?If so, could you please show me an example of the `public class utils` method?I'm a bit confused on how to implement it

Comment: I'm sorry for being a total beginner but I don't understand how to add the `position` into `public static array`. I don't know if this affect much but I can only declare `public ArrayList<Integer> positions`. Adding `static` seems to give me an error

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful and educational

Answer (score 0):

Well you just remove the desired item from the list using the remove() method of your ArrayAdapter.

A possible way to do that would be:

`Object toRemove = arrayAdapter.getItem([POSITION]);
arrayAdapter.remove(toRemove);`

Another way would be to modify the ArrayList and call notifyDataSetChanged() on the ArrayAdapter.

```
arrayList.remove([INDEX]);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Okay,I can use that to delete, but what about to edit?

Comment: https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/